# How to promisify Node's child_process.exec and child_process.execFile functions with Bluebird?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using the Bluebird promise library under Node.js, it's great! But I have a question:

If you take a look at the documentation of Node's [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and [child_process.execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) you can see that both of these functions are returning a ChildProcess object.

So what's the recommended way to promisify such functions?

Note that the following works (I get a Promise object):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var execAsync = Promise.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
var execFileAsync = Promise.promisify(require('child_process').execFile);
```

But how can one get access to the original return value of the original Node.js functions? (In these cases I would need to be able to access the originally returned ChildProcess objects.)

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is an example code which is using the return value of the child_process.exec function:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('node ./commands/server.js');
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
child.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('closing code: ' + code);
});
```

But if I would use the promisified version of the exec function ( execAsync from above ) then the return value will be a promise, not a ChildProcess object. This is the real problem I am talking about.

Comment: Do you need both the promise and the `ChildProcess` instance? A code example of how you would like to use the desired function would be helpful.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, exactly! I would have needed both the promise and the child process object. It's more like a theoretical question really, because I solved my problem. But here is what I wanted to do: I wanted to execute a program with child_process.execFile and then I wanted to feed (pipe) data into its stdin and read its stdout. And I needed a promise, because of promise chaining. Anyhow, I worked around it by promisifying child_process.exec instead of execFile and run the program via a shell like this: `prg <input >output`. But now I must shell escape everything (both on Windows and *nix) ...

Comment: If you just want to access stdout/err, you don't need the returned object. Because stdout/err are parameters to the callback function.

Comment: Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-promise and it's associated code (https://github.com/patrick-steele-idem/child-process-promise).

Comment: Or you might like the API of https://github.com/jcoreio/promisify-child-process, which allows you to simply `const {stdout, stderr} = await exec('echo test')`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like to return two things from the call:

- the ChildProcess
- a promise that resolves when the ChildProcess completes

So "the recommended way to promisify such functions"? **Don't**.

You're outside the convention. Promise returning functions are expected to return a promise, and that's it. You could return an object with two members (the ChildProcess & the promise), but that'll just confuse people.

I'd suggest calling the unpromisified function, and creating a promise based off the returned childProcess. (Maybe wrap that into a helper function)

This way, it's quite explicit for the next person who reads the code.

Something like:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

function promiseFromChildProcess(child) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        child.addListener("error", reject);
        child.addListener("exit", resolve);
    });
}

var child = exec('ls');

promiseFromChildProcess(child).then(function (result) {
    console.log('promise complete: ' + result);
}, function (err) {
    console.log('promise rejected: ' + err);
});

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
child.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('closing code: ' + code);
});
```

If you're just wanting to promisify specifically `child_process.exec()` and `child_process.execFile()`, in recent node versions there is a better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63027900/4729).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, got me started on the right track! I needed to tweak it slightly so that exit codes are properly handled: `child.addListener('exit', (code, signal) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });`

Comment: In the `child.stderr.on` callback, logging `stderr` instead of `stdout` would be clearer.

Comment: +1 for this question/answer; inspired by this answer, I found [`parallel-mochas.js`](https://github.com/elricdesigns/virtualbox/blob/080e19f27d0760839f44623089cd4ec2f600b015/ustwo-example/src/src/app/lib/parallel-mochas.js) which is a similar example using ES6 promises and not the bluebird dependency.

Comment: wouldn't it be better here to use `.catch(err) instead of using the reject handler in `.then()`?

Answer (score 358):

I would recommend using standard JS promises built into the language over an additional library dependency like Bluebird.

If you're using Node 10+, [the Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) recommend using `util.promisify` which returns a `Promise<{ stdout, stderr }>` object. See an example below:

```js
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function lsExample() {
  try {
    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('ls');
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    console.log('stderr:', stderr);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e); // should contain code (exit code) and signal (that caused the termination).
  }
}
lsExample()
```

Handle errors first from `stderr`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it works for many other callback-based functions too

Comment: This answer ignores the core premise of the question: "access the originally returned ChildProcess objects".

Comment: Work in TypeScript too

Comment: Unfortunately, `stderr` is not available if an error is thrown (even if defining `stdout` and `stderr` above the `try` block), which makes troubleshooting quite difficult.

Answer (score 59):

Since Node v12 the built-in `util.promisify` allows access to the `ChildProcess` object in the returned `Promise` for built-in functions where it would have been returned by the un-promisified call. From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback):

> The returned `ChildProcess` instance is attached to the `Promise` as a `child` property.

This correctly and simply satisfies the need to access `ChildProcess` in the original question and makes **other answers out of date** providing that Node v12+ can be used.

Adapting the example (and *concise* style) provided by the questioner, access to the `ChildProcess` can be achieved like:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
const promise = exec('node ./commands/server.js');
const child = promise.child; 

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
child.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('closing code: ' + code);
});

// i.e. can then await for promisified exec call to complete
const { stdout, stderr } = await promise;
```

Comment: Nice! Looks like introduced in [v12.6.0 ](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/28508)

Comment:  lots of googling to find this example. Thank you! Obviously this is doable with manual Promise construction but this solution is a lot more readable.

Comment: command 'java -version' breaks this code. `const promise = exec('java -version');`

Answer (score 36):

Here's another way:

```
function execPromise(command) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
                return;
            }

            resolve(stdout.trim());
        });
    });
}
```

Use the function:

```
execPromise(command).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
});
```

Or with async/await:

```
try {
    var result = await execPromise(command);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
}
```

Comment: This is not suitable if you want to stream stdout or stderr, for instance when they are very sizeable.

Comment: You can also use `util.promisify` and then access `.stdout`.

Comment: @Lucas You should post it as answer. `const execAsync = require('util').promisify(require('child_process').exec);`

Answer (score 9):

There's probably not a way to do nicely that covers all use cases. But for limited cases, you can do something like this:

```
/**
 * Promisified child_process.exec
 *
 * @param cmd
 * @param opts See child_process.exec node docs
 * @param {stream.Writable} opts.stdout If defined, child process stdout will be piped to it.
 * @param {stream.Writable} opts.stderr If defined, child process stderr will be piped to it.
 *
 * @returns {Promise<{ stdout: string, stderr: stderr }>}
 */
function execp(cmd, opts) {
    opts || (opts = {});
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const child = exec(cmd, opts,
            (err, stdout, stderr) => err ? reject(err) : resolve({
                stdout: stdout,
                stderr: stderr
            }));

        if (opts.stdout) {
            child.stdout.pipe(opts.stdout);
        }
        if (opts.stderr) {
            child.stderr.pipe(opts.stderr);
        }
    });
}
```

This accepts `opts.stdout` and `opts.stderr` arguments, so that stdio can be captured from the child process.

For example:

```
execp('ls ./', {
    stdout: new stream.Writable({
        write: (chunk, enc, next) => {
            console.log(chunk.toString(enc));
            next();
        }
    }),
    stderr: new stream.Writable({
        write: (chunk, enc, next) => {
            console.error(chunk.toString(enc));
            next();
        }
    })
}).then(() => console.log('done!'));
```

Or simply:

```
execp('ls ./', {
    stdout: process.stdout,
    stderr: process.stderr
}).then(() => console.log('done!'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Just want to mention that there's a nice tool that will solve your problem completely:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-worker

This package makes it a lot easier to handle processes.

```
import { process } from "CoreWorker";
import fs from "fs";

const result = await process("node Server.js", "Server is ready.").ready(1000);
const result = await process("cp path/to/file /newLocation/newFile").death();
```

or combine these functions:

```
import { process } from "core-worker";

const simpleChat = process("node chat.js", "Chat ready");

setTimeout(() => simpleChat.kill(), 360000); // wait an hour and close the chat

simpleChat.ready(500)
    .then(console.log.bind(console, "You are now able to send messages."))
    .then(::simpleChat.death)
    .then(console.log.bind(console, "Chat closed"))
    .catch(() => /* handle err */);
```

Comment: Based on this recommendation, I went off and used core-worker. I found it to be extremely opaque with regards to providing output and found that it would throw non-zero exit codes when commands completed properly. I would not use that library.

Comment: May you be so kind and open an issue / issues if you're having trouble with the lib? We're using it everywhere where it comes to external processes and it's a core lib of our functional test suite used in dozens of productive projects.

Answer (score 4):

Just another example you might run into issues when running multiple commands when destructuring with the same const's you can rename them like this.

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function runCommands() {
    try {
        const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('ls');
        console.log('stdout:', stdout);
        console.log('stderr:', stderr);

        const { stdout: stdoutTwo, stderr: stderrTwo } = await exec('ls');
        console.log('stdoutTwo:', stdoutTwo);
        console.log('stderrTwo:', stderrTwo);

        const { stdout: stdoutThree, stderr: stderrThree } = await exec('ls');
        console.log('stdoutThree:', stdoutThree);
        console.log('stderrThree:', stderrThree);

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e); // should contain code (exit code) and signal (that caused the termination).
    }
}
runCommands()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are my two cents. Uses spawn which streams the output and writes to `stdout` and `stderr`. The error and standard output is captured in buffers and are returned or rejected.

*This is written I Typescript, feel free to remove typings if using JavaScript:*

```
import { spawn, SpawnOptionsWithoutStdio } from 'child_process'

const spawnAsync = async (
  command: string,
  options?: SpawnOptionsWithoutStdio
) =>
  new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
    const [spawnCommand, ...args] = command.split(/\s+/);
    const spawnProcess = spawn(spawnCommand, args, options);
    const chunks: Buffer[] = [];
    const errorChunks: Buffer[] = [];
    spawnProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      process.stdout.write(data.toString());
      chunks.push(data);
    });
    spawnProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
      process.stderr.write(data.toString());
      errorChunks.push(data);
    });
    spawnProcess.on("error", (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
    spawnProcess.on("close", (code) => {
      if (code === 1) {
        reject(Buffer.concat(errorChunks).toString());
        return;
      }
      resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Other examples did not work for me becuase a lot of commands did not return output, the stdout and std error, thus failed to emit.

No output is often good output for a shell command.

Node js has the native async await using util.promisify in their [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) but it did not work for me for the same reason (not emitting close and exit events).

```
const util = require('node:util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('node:child_process').exec);
const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('ls');.
```

Promise wrapper was mentioned in the answer by @LachoTomov but that failed to return anythign from my parent async function. This is an improvement on that after discovering the other events emitted, not featured in most of the code examples in the nodejs documentation but listed in the [ChildProcess class properties documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#class-childprocess).

```
   const { exec } = require('child_process')

    let res = await execChild_process(`ls ${var}`)
    console.log('result', res)

    async function execChild_process(command) {
    /**
     * Commands with no output send the exit event.
     */
    console.log('\n execChild_process command : ', command)
    let output = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        childProcess = exec(command)
        childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            resolve(`exec success: ${data}`)
        })
        childProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            resolve(`stderr error: ${data}`)
        })
        childProcess.on('close', (code) => {
            resolve(`exec success: 'close'  ${code}`)
        })
        childProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
            resolve(`exec success: 'exit' ${code}`)
        })
        childProcess.on('error', (error) => {
            resolve(`exec error: ${error}`)
        })
    });
    return output
}
```

There are also a couple other events, like disconnect, message, and spawn, that could be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine.  It doesn't deal with stdin or stdout, so if you need those then use one of the other answers on this page.  :)

```
// promisify `child_process`
// This is a very nice trick :-)
this.promiseFromChildProcess = function (child) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        child.addListener('error', (code, signal) => {
            console.log('ChildProcess error', code, signal);
            reject(code);
        });
        child.addListener('exit', (code, signal) => {
            if (code === 0) {
                resolve(code);
            } else {
                console.log('ChildProcess error', code, signal);
                reject(code);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Welp, maybe this is not the first option you want to try to solve yours problems with 'child_process' but I can confirm this actually works.