# Node Child Process Exec Command Failed with error code 1

Tags: node.js, cmd, typescript, visual-studio-code, child-process

I am trying to execute some line using node js child process and getting error.
Following is my code:

```
let cmd : string = "code " + PROJECTS[value];
exec(cmd, function callback(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log("started console app");
});
```

**ERROR :**

```
cmd:"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "code c:\Users\shana\Dropbox\code-settings-syn... (length: 82)"
code:1
killed:false
message:"Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "code c:\Users\shana\Dropbox\c... (length: 99)"
signal:null
stack:undefined
```

Detail of error JSON.

```
Full CMD : "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "code c:\Users\shana\Dropbox\code-settings-sync""
Full message : "Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "code c:\Users\shana\Dropbox\code-settings-sync"\n"
```

Comment: Try to copy full command from your programm and execute it by hand in terminal.

Comment: its working when i copy and run the command in terminal but here after running 1,2 time i gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a simpler example ..

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'code C:\Program Files';
exec(cmd, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
if (err) {
console.error(err);
return;
}
console.log(stdout); 
});
```

does this work??

Comment: the problem is that it works 1,2 times this example and my example after that same error popups

Comment: verify the string you are passing to exec command or storing in array . is it properly escaped in terms of your os

Comment: yes you can check the full CMD in the code i have shown and its working fine in Windows when i write in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to see the whole error (too verbose) so I did something like this:

```
try { 
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('echo TEST');
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.log('stderr:', stderr);
} catch (e) {
  // If exec fails and you want to see the whole ugly error: 
  // console.error(e);
  console.log('How about a nice human readable message instead?'); 
}
```

Because of the "await" this goes inside an "async" function.
More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56095793/722796