# Better way to handle mochajs timeout

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to implement mocha testing, however it doesn't seem to work the way I expect it to. My code looks like the following:

```js
async function getFoo() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved')
    }, 2500)
  })
}

describe(`Testing stuff`, function () {
  it('resolves with foo', () => {
    return getFoo().then(result => {
      assert.equal(result, 'foo')
    })
  })
})
```

Error message:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

To me it seems like I have to increase the threshold of the timeout.
Is there a better way to do this? Since I don't know how long each test might take. I am testing nodejs child processes

best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default timeout for mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492043/change-default-timeout-for-mocha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is described in the error you need to use `done()` end of your test.

```
function delay(timeout = 2500) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved')
    }, timeout)
  })
}

describe(`Testing stuff`, function (done) {
  it('resolves with foo', (done) => {
    return delay().then(result => {
      assert.equal(result, 'foo') 
      done()
    })
  })
});

// better readability

describe(`Testing stuff`, function (done) {
  it('resolves with foo', (done) => {
    const result = await delay();
    assert.equal(result, 'foo') 
    done();
  })
});
```

But as you described you are testing child_processes which I don't recommend. Because to test child_process you need to `promisify` the child_process which doesn't make sense. Check here for more info [How to promisify Node's child_process.exec and child_process.execFile functions with Bluebird?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763496/how-to-promisify-nodes-child-process-exec-and-child-process-execfile-functions)

If you really want to test child_process maybe you can mock the process with the link i gave but only for testing purposes.